# Why CGColorRef does not change the CALayer properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I wanted to change view properties using CALayer associated with it.

[image: similar like this]

I have created one function:

```js
-(void)setupViewLayer{
    viewLayer1.backgroundColor  = (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor blueColor]);
    viewLayer1.borderColor  =(__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor redColor]);
    viewLayer1.borderWidth = 100.0;
    viewLayer1.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
    viewLayer1.shadowRadius = 10.0;
}
```

viewLayer1 is view's layer whose properties I want to change.
But the view does not show the properties.
 Is there anything else I need to change? Please help.

Comment: `But the view does not show the properties.` - Which properties?

Comment: Can you update why this happening? It w'd be helpful to future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code -

```
viewLayer1.backgroundColor  = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
viewLayer1.borderColor  = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
viewLayer1.borderWidth = 100.0;
viewLayer1.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
viewLayer1.shadowRadius = 10.0;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set Color by,

```
viewLayer1.backgroundColor  = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
viewLayer1.borderColor  = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Thanks, Lal Krishna. It resolved my issue. But may I know the difference? actually both way we are trying to convert into CGColorRef.